# Getting up-to-date data from entity that has One-To-One relation and data is updated externally

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Instead of explaining my question, I will try to give an example:

Let's say I have a `User` entity and a `Item` entity. `User` entity has one-to-one relation to `Item`.

Let's say that at some point my server updates The table using a sql-update query.

and my question is: Next time I do something like:

```
Item item = user.getItem();
```

How can I make sure that the data is up-to-date ? and not the old data that was initially read from DB when User instance was first queried?

Hope my question is clear...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can be certain about updated entities by flushing entity manager after the DML commands and then query the object again.

Regards
Himanshu

Comment: If I query User entity again I would certainly get it updated, but I was wondering if there is a way doing it without querying, maybe with a proxy and invalidate and then validate instance of something like that...

Comment: You can always write a listener which can update the entity values in the object in action but that will be too much of effort for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in the new session, then it will be up to date (if you don't use L2 cache for the entities in question).

If you use L2 cache, then it will not be up to date (if the data is updated in the database without Hibernate being aware of it). In this case, if it is ok for your use cases to use stale data for a specific time interval, you can configure expiration policy for `User` and `Item` entities, so that their lifespan in the cache is limited. After they expire from the cache, updated data will be fetched from the database.

If you can properly invalidate the affected second-level cache entries upon changing the data in the background, then you can avoid using the stale data entirely (or reduce the possible time interval in which they will be used as stale).

If you do it in the existing session instance, then both `Item` and `User` instances will be in the first-level cache, so you will always get the data that were initially fetched. This is almost always the desired behavior. However, you can manually evict an entity instance (`session.evict(item); session.evict(user)`) or clear the entire session (`session.clear()`) to evict all the instances from the current session and then re-read them again from the database.

Comment: The flow goes like this: 1) User is first queried from DB along with it's Item instance. 2) User instance is stored in Hazelcast distributed cache.
3) From time to time the Item instance has to be updated not via it's User but externally. 4) later on I would like to access User instance and get up-to-date Item instance.

Comment: 1) Is Hazelcast configured as second-level cache provider for Hibernate? 2) You are caching only `Users` but not `Items`?

Comment: Both User and Item are in 2nd level cache. because Item is associated to User in One-To-One relation.